# Android: aapt.exe exception

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

While sync my project am getting an **aapt.exe exception**. I Changed the build version i build.gradle but still I am getting the error

While cleaning the app am getting

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Binil\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Can any one please help me to solve this issue
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Rebuild your project.Backup/delete your build folder. Run lint and check whether any error exist or not

Comment: I delete all temp folder in Android Studio and rebuild the project. But still am getting same exception. How run lint ??   Madhukar Hebbar

Comment: If you are using android studio then
`Menu-> Code -> Inspect Code -> Whole Project`  Then press Ok. After completing click on the inspection tab which is normally left below of your IDE then click on `Group inspections by Severity` which will show errors in your android project. Also please post full gradle error trace.